# Creating XMLDocument throguh code in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument

am trying to generate an XML document like this through code.

```
<TestRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd">
    <Version>3</Version>
    <ApplicationHeader>
        <AppLanguage />
        <UserId>rmservice</UserId>
    </ApplicationHeader>
    <CustomerData>
        <ExistingCustomerData>
            <MTN>2084127182</MTN>
        </ExistingCustomerData>
    </CustomerData>
</TestRequest>
```

I tried some samples. But they create xmlns for the children, which i dont need. Any help is really appreciated.

I have tried the below code. But it is adding only xmlns to all children, which i dont need

```
XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "windows-1252", null));
XmlElement xRoot = xDocument.CreateElement("TestRequest", "XNamespace.Xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" + " xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=" + "http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd");
xDocument.AppendChild(xRoot);
xRoot.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateElement("Version")).InnerText = 1;
```

Thanks
Tutu

I have tried with

```
var xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            XmlElement xRoot = xDocument.CreateElement("xsi","RMRequest",xsi);
            xRoot.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", xsi, "http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd");

            xDocument.AppendChild(xRoot);
Now the response is 

<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1252\"?><xsi:TestRequest xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
```

Comment: Do you definitely need to use XmlDocument? LINQ to XML is generally simpler. Also, you should show what you've already tried, so we can try to help you fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the awesome LINQ to XML. Enjoy!

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "windows-1252", null),  
    new XElement("TestRequest",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        new XAttribute(xsi + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd"),
        new XElement("Version",
                new XText("3")
        ),
        new XElement("ApplicationHeader",
                new XElement("AppLanguage"),
                new XElement("UserId",
                        new XText("rmservice")
                )
        ),
        new XElement("CustomerData",
            new XElement("ExistingCustomerData",
                new XElement("MTN", 
                    new XText("2084127182")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

doc.Save(filePath);
```

If you really want the old API, here it is:

```
var xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "windows-1252", null));

var xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var xRoot = xDocument.CreateElement("TestRequest");

var attr = xDocument.CreateAttribute("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", xsi);
attr.Value = "http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd";
xRoot.Attributes.Append(attr);

xRoot.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateElement("Version")).InnerText = "1";

// ..  your other elemets ...

xDocument.AppendChild(xRoot);
xDocument.Save(filePath);
```

**EDIT**: From your comments, it looks like you want the `xmlns:xsi` and other attribute in that specific order. If so, you may have to trick the `XmlDocument` to add the `xmlns:xsi` attribute first.

```
var xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "windows-1252", null));

var xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var xRoot = xDocument.CreateElement("TestRequest");

// add namespace decl are attribute
var attr = xDocument.CreateAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
attr.Value = xsi;
xRoot.Attributes.Append(attr);

// no need to specify prefix, XmlDocument will figure it now
attr = xDocument.CreateAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", xsi);
attr.Value = "http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd";
xRoot.Attributes.Append(attr);

xRoot.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateElement("Version")).InnerText = "1";

// ..  your other elemets ...

xDocument.AppendChild(xRoot);
xDocument.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: Now getting <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1252\"?><xsi:TestRequest xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">

Comment: var xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            XmlElement xRoot = xDocument.CreateElement("xsi","RMRequest",xsi);
            xRoot.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", xsi, "http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd");

            xDocument.AppendChild(xRoot); Now m

Comment: I've edited my answer some time back to remove that bug which adds `xsi` to root element. Refresh your page and see my answer.

Comment: Now getting <TestRequest xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"> Can i get it as <RMRequest xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"http://localhost:2292/RMSchema.xsd\" >

Comment: sure, change `var xRoot = xDocument.CreateElement("TestRequest");` to `var xRoot = xDocument.CreateElement("RMRequest");`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:-

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode root = xmldoc.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Root"));
XmlNode child = root.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Child"));
XmlAttribute childAtt =child.Attributes.Append(xmldoc.CreateAttribute("Attribute"));
childAtt.InnerText = "My innertext";
child.InnerText = "My node Innertext";
xmldoc.Save("ABC.xml");
```