# Adding attribute in XMLDocument's child element - C#

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I'm not able to get my expected result. Look at my C# code I am adding the second attribute
"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" , But the word "xsi:" is missing in the outerXml. Where I'm failing?

**c# :**

```
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
    {
        new XmlSerializer(oWrite.GetType()).Serialize(writer, oWrite);
    }
   doc.DocumentElement.RemoveAllAttributes() ;
   XmlAttribute xmlAtri1,xmlAtri2;         
   xmlAtri1 = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
   xmlAtri1.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";  
   doc.FirstChild.FirstChild.Attributes.Append(xmlAtri1);
   xmlAtri2 = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation");
   xmlAtri2.Value = "../xsd/nikuxog_customObjectInstance.xsd";
   doc.FirstChild.FirstChild.Attributes.Append(xmlAtri2);          
   return doc.DocumentElement  ;
```

**Outer XML :**

```
<WriteCustomObjectInstance>
  <NikuDataBus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/nikuxog_customObjectInstance.xsd">
    <Header externalSource="NIKU" version="13.1.0.0248" />
    <customObjectInstances objectCode="web_req">
    </customObjectInstances>
  </NikuDataBus>
</WriteCustomObjectInstance>
```

**Expected XML :**

```
<WriteCustomObjectInstance>
   <NikuDataBus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/nikuxog_customObjectInstance.xsd">
    <Header externalSource="NIKU" version="13.1.0.0248" />
    <customObjectInstances objectCode="web_req">
    </customObjectInstances>
  </NikuDataBus>
</WriteCustomObjectInstance>
```

Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this -

```
   doc.DocumentElement.RemoveAllAttributes() ;
   var xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
   XmlAttribute xmlAtri1;         
   xmlAtri1 = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
   xmlAtri1.Value = xsi;  
   doc.FirstChild.FirstChild.Attributes.Append(xmlAtri1);
   xmlAtri1 = doc.CreateAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", xsi);
   xmlAtri1.Value = "../xsd/nikuxog_customObjectInstance.xsd";
   doc.FirstChild.FirstChild.Attributes.Append(xmlAtri1);
```

For details check this link -

[Creating XMLDocument throguh code in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387538/creating-xmldocument-throguh-code-in-asp-net)

Comment: I'm serializing my object to XMLDocument.I can't create XDocument.

Comment: xDocument is object of XmlDocument in the given link. Please check the link provided.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387538/creating-xmldocument-throguh-code-in-asp-net